# ( ! ) Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Exception Occured while migrating joomla 1.5 to 2.5

Tags: joomla, joomla2.5, joomla1.5, joomla-extensions

I'm trying to migrate my joomla website from 1.5.26 to 2.5. While migrating the joomla website through jupgrade extension, it is showing me "Migrating undefined". So, i've on the migration error in jupgrade extension then it shows me the following error which are related to the j25_users table.
Please have alook at the following error:-

```
( ! ) Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Exception' with message 'Unknown column 'subscribe' in 'field list' SQL=INSERT INTO `j25_users` (`id`,`name`,`username`,`email`,`password`,`usertype`,`block`,`sendEmail`,`registerDate`,`lastvisitDate`,`activation`,`params`,`subscribe`) VALUES ('62','ChhathPoojaAdmin','admin','info@vivid-techno.com','36b6db909a7471b4e6fdf31b4eec641e:UELuOKlpIjy0jqPf36I8Kzj8uNElGBf9','Super Administrator','0','1','2010-06-27 16:18:02','2013-01-21 12:36:40','','{\"admin_language\":\"en-GB\",\"language\":\"en-GB\",\"editor\":\"xstandard\",\"helpsite\":\"\",\"timezone\":\"UTC\"}','1')' in C:\wamp\www\jdchhath\administrator\components\com_jupgrade\includes\jupgrade.class.php on line 347
```

Any Guess, how to solve it?

Comment: have you added in extra coloumns to the table? because as far as I'm aware there shouldn't be a subscribe table in the users table.

Comment: The problem was that in joomla 2.5 users table there are no subscribe field in their users table which i al;ready figured it out on last nyt, so what i've done was added an extra column in my table #__users and then upgraded again. It was successfully upgraded to joomla 2.5 :))Thanks to you also...:)))

Comment: No worries. write your solution down in the answer box and accept it so people can see in the future if they have the same problem :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Upgrading your old joomla website to latest joomla version can be hectic as it could make you to feel so angry. The answer of my solution was that the subscribe column was not in the latest joomla version that makes it problem to upgrade my website to latest version. So i inserted myself the column table "subscribe" in my #__users table and please note that don't delete the old database tables which has been created by the jupgrde even if it is unsuccessful.That's it and you are done. If you are encounting any other problems related to database then first of all make sure that columns or tables are exist or not in your database. If jupgrade extensions creates any new database other than these tables jupgrade_categories,jupgrade_menus,jupgrade_modules,jupgrade_steps than don't delete it from my opinion.Just add the new columns or table in the newly created tables  by jupgrade